# Cron fails on single apostrophe

Tags: unix, cron

The following does work as expected:

```
date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M'

28-Sep-2009-14-28
```

But none of the following 4 entries from crontab are working.

```
* * * * * date +\'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M\' >> /backup/shantanu/testing.txt
* * * * * date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M' >> /backup/shantanu/testing1.txt
* * * * * date +"%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M" >> /backup/shantanu/testing2.txt
* * * * * date +\"%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M\" >> /backup/shantanu/testing3.txt
```

```
Error:
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I can save the same code in a shell script and set the cron, but I will like to know if it is possible to directly set a cron for the task.

The actual cron entry that I am trying to set looks something like this...

```
16 * * * * mysqldump myDB myTB > /backup/ABCbc$(date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M').sql 2> /backup/ABCbc_errORS$(date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M').txt
```

Comment: If you resolved your problem, please post it as an answer.

Comment: 58 13 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot -pPassWord --compact --databases db1 db2 db3 db4 | zip > /home/develop/backup/central_mydt$(date +'\%d\%m\%y').zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is % special in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277508/how-is-special-in-crontab)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are four common causes for cron job commands to behave differently compared to commands typed directly into an interactive shell:

- Cron provides a limited environment, e.g., a minimal `$PATH`, and other expected variables missing.
- Cron invokes `/bin/sh` by default, whereas you may be using some other shell interactively.
- Cron treats the `%` character specially (it is turned into a newline in the command).
- The command may behave differently because it doesn't have a terminal available.

You must precede all `%` characters with a `\` in a crontab file, which tells cron to just put a `%` in the command, e.g.

```
16 * * * * mysqldump myDB myTB > "/backup/ABCbc$(date +'\%d-\%b-\%Y-\%H-\%M').sql" 2> "/backup/ABCbc_errORS$(date +'\%d-\%b-\%Y-\%H-\%M').txt"
```

(As a separate matter, always put double quotes around a `"$variable_substitution"` or a `"$(command substitution)"`, unless you know why not do it in a particular case. Otherwise, if the variable contents or command output contains whitespace or `?*\[`, they will be interpreted by the shell.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no spaces in the format string supplied as an argument to date, you should not need the ticks at all.

```
date +%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M
```

should work.

Comment: I removed the quotes as mentioned above and it still does not work from cron. It runs fine from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a syntax not supported by /bin/sh.  Try invoking your preferred shell and passing the command as an argument.