# Syntax error only when command is run from cron

Tags: unix, command-line, cron

This command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u myuser -pmypass mydb > "/home/myuser/dbBackups/"`date +%Y%m%d`".sql"
```

works fine from the command line but whenb cron runs it I get

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The command is all on one line in the crontab as well so I'm confused by the line 0 and line 1 references...

Can anyone advise me as to what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: When you're running from the command line, are you using the same shell as cron uses (/bin/sh)?

Comment: Mentioning which unix would be helpful.
The only thing I can guess from available information is that your login shell may not be /bin/sh, so try running /bin/sh and then running your command.
Oh, also check to make sure you don't have a tab character in place of the space in there accidentally - cron might get confused by that.

Comment: Ah!  I am running bash and cron is not.  Any notion what the correct backtick syntax is in /bin/sh ?  I am really only familiar with bash.

The server is Linux.

Comment: Hmm, the syntax you are using works on sh on the Linux box I tried, but you may have a different version.
Can you paste the output of sh --version here?
Also, to verify there are no extra characters in cron, can you paste how this line appears when you run:
    crontab -l | cat -vet

Comment: Backquotes are the same on /bin/sh as on bash.

Comment: Similar question, same answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486088/cron-fails-on-single-apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486088/cron-fails-on-single-apostrophe)

Comment: After using the shell script approach to solve problem I saw that I could have specified the shell under which cron runs from within the crontab.  Useful info for the future!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron fails on single apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486088/cron-fails-on-single-apostrophe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest fix is probably to put the whole command in a shell script and just have that be run. So make a scriptName.sh file that contains the command you listed and have crontab call that script. That gets around all these odd problems.

Comment: I've been trying for an hour now to have cron run a .sh and all I get is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".  Bloody linux!

Answer (score 5):

It's the obvious dumb question, but do you have the matching backquote in your crontab (`crontab -l`)?

The line one, line zero stuff isn't referring to the lines in the crontab, only to the 'lines' in the one-line script.

**Updated:**

Ah, I think I've got it.  This is from crontab(5):

```
Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\),
will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the
first % will be sent to the command as standard input.
```

So the percent characters in your date spec are being interpreted as newlines, which means the backquote isn't terminated before the newline, which would produce your error message.

So escape the percent characters.  I'd forgotten that about crontab....

Comment: Sure do; the cmd above is exactly it minus the actual un/pw/db name.

Answer (score 1):

Commands executed from cron do not have access to the environment variables from your login shell, including the path.  So try the following (adding fully qualified path to date):

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --add-drop-table -u myuser -pmypass mydb > "/home/myuser/dbBackups/"`/usr/bin/date +%Y%m%d`".sql"
```

Of course, verify if your `date` command is located elsewhere by running `which date` then adjust the path if necessary.

Comment: This is an excellent point I will bear in mind in the future.  Did not solve this issue but I definitely should have made sure the full path was included there.