# How is % (percent sign) special in crontab?

Tags: shell, unix, cron

In crontab, can you do something like this?

```
* * * * * echo $( date +%F) >> /path/date.txt
```

Comment: mail show me this.   
/bin/sh -c " echo $( date +  
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'  
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), though.  Anything which looks like `echo $(foo)` is better written simply `foo` (unless you specifically use an unquoted command substitution to cause the shell to normalize whitespace and expand wildcards in the output from `foo`).

Comment: @tripleee I agree, but the problematic useless thing is more the *fork* (`$(...)`), than the *builtin* `echo`!  ;-) Posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77557871/1765658) with an use sample of percent sign!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The actual problem of your crontab line is not the `$()` or the backquotes. The problem is the percent sign `%`. It has a special meaning in crontabs.

From the manpage:

```
...
Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), 
will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the 
first % will be sent to the command  as standard input.
...
```

If you escape the percent sign with `\` it should work as expected:

```
* * * * * echo $(date +\%F) >> /tmp/date.txt
```

or

```
* * * * * echo `date +\%F` >> /tmp/date2.txt
```

both work on my site.

Comment: Be aware that the backslashes are passed to the shell.  So a command like the one above will work because the shell strips the backslash, but a backslash inside a string will be left in by the shell, as per http://www.hcidata.info/crontab.htm

Comment: I hate cron with a vengeance

Comment: Why `echo $(date +\%F)` instead of just `date +\%F` ?

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: Just because of the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> ### How is % (percent sign) special in crontab?

Have a look at man page:  `man -Pless\ +/% 5 crontab`

> ... Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters...

### Your example

First avoid useless forks ( `echo $(date +%F)` is useless. ) !

```
* * * * * date +\%F >> /path/date.txt
```

### Another sample

```
* * * * * cat >>$(date +testfile-\%F.txt)%This is 3 more lines%in same file%Uh!
```

This will add 3 more lines into a daily file.

Or even, mixing bash in crontab:

```
* * * * * bash >>$(date +testfile-\%F.txt)%echo This is 3 more lines%echo in same file%printf '\%(\%a \%d \%b)T Uh!\n'
```

But don't do this, it's unreadable!