# List of characters which needs to be escaped in a linux shell command

Tags: java, regex, bash

In Linux and other OS, file can contain characters like `(,),[,],<space>,` etc. in their names.
Whenever I try to use any of these files in my bash command like cat, ls, etc. I am required to escape them like below :

```
filename abc(10-oct).txt
cat abc(10-oct).txt wont work.
```

If I precede `"("` and `")"` characters with `"\"` character like

```
cat abc\(10-oct\).txt
```

This works

I am trying to automate some of Linux shell commands via Java program.And I am not sure of what all characters I must take care of and escape them.

If someone may point to a resource where I can get an entire list of characters, it would be a great help.

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-bash-how-do-we-know-it/15784162#15784162

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Single Quote `'filename'` which will escape everything needs to be escaped in shell mode

Comment: yes, kind of like `cat 'abc(10-oct).txt'` will work out just fine .

Comment: ok.. I was not aware of that.. I will try this.. and definitely accept as answer

Comment: Except a pesky single quote ', which can't be escaped.

Comment: You can use `"foo'.txt"` for single quotes. Worst case scenario, `"foo\"'\$.txt"`.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting from [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html):

> The following characters must be quoted if they are to represent
>   themselves:
>
> `` |  &  ;  <  >  (  )  $  `  \  "  '  <space>  <tab>  <newline> ``
>
> and the following may need to be quoted under certain circumstances.
>   That is, these characters may be special depending on conditions
>   described elsewhere in this specification:
>
> `*   ?   [   #   ~   =   %`
>
> The various quoting mechanisms are the escape character, single-quotes
>   and double-quotes.

It also says:

> Enclosing characters in single-quotes (' ') preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the single-quotes. A single-quote
>   cannot occur within single-quotes.

And:

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes (" ") preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception
>   of the characters dollar-sign, backquote and backslash...