# how to escape '=' character in ansible playbook

Tags: escaping, ansible

I have a playbook like this:

```
- name: make a http request
  shell: wget -O /dev/null http://my.site.com/some/url?with=args
```

The main problem is the GET Arguments. There is an "=" character that I don't know how to escape properly.
If I do not escape this, ansible thinks that it's another argument for module, but if I escape it, then it make double escaping so as a result I've got "/=" in the shell.

Ansible version: 1.7.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-bash-how-do-we-know-it

Comment: problem is not in bash escaping, problem is in escaping inside ansible playbook

Answer (score 1):

With little help the problem was found.

Problem was actually in Ansible 1.7.1. After upgrading to 1.7.2 the problem was solved.

Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this with a bare call to `wget`. I'm using my gravatar as a URL with args. Here's a sample call.

```
TASK: [shell wget -O /dev/null https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cad260683598a6e41608b91a9b57099b?s=24] ***
```

And here's the debugging output:

```
<hostname> REMOTE_MODULE command wget -O /dev/null https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cad260683598a6e41608b91a9b57099b?s=24 #USE_SHELL
... connected.\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\nLength: 1089 (1.1K) [image/jpeg]\nSaving to: `/dev/null'\n\n     0K .                                                     100% 1.93M=0.001s\n\n2014-10-31 16:52:00 (1.93 MB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [1089/1089]", "stdout": ""}
```

Generally speaking, using `command`, `shell`, and `lineinfile` are a form of code smell. In this case, it means using [the `get_url` module](http://docs.ansible.com/get_url_module.html) or [the `uri` module](http://docs.ansible.com/uri_module.html). `wget` generally implies `get_url`, but you are throwing away the output, so you are using it like `curl`, which means the `uri` module is better.

Here's my playbook. I needed to add `pip` since httplib wasn't installed on my test host.

```
  tasks:
  - debug: var=hostvars
  - pip: name=httplib2
    sudo: yes
  - uri: url=https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cad260683598a6e41608b91a9b57099b?s=24
```

You can see in the verbose output that it's making the correct call.

```
ok: [hostname] => {"accept_ranges": "bytes", "access_control_allow_origin": "*", "cache_control": "max-age=300", "changed": false, "content_disposition": "inline; filename=\"cad260683598a6e41608b91a9b57099b.jpeg\"", "content_length": "1089", "content_location": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cad260683598a6e41608b91a9b57099b?s=24", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "date": "Fri, 31 Oct 2014 16:58:42 GMT", "expires": "Fri, 31 Oct 2014 17:03:42 GMT", "last_modified": "Fri, 04 Nov 2011 16:27:09 GMT", "link": "<https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cad260683598a6e41608b91a9b57099b?s=24>; rel=\"canonical\"", "redirected": false, "server": "ECS (ams/49F2)", "source_age": "81", "status": 200, "via": "1.1 varnish", "x_cache": "HIT", "x_varnish": "3775458975 3775177699"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the problem, looks like it was a bug in 1.7.1 version.
The reason why I`m using shell with wget, because I tried to use commands with minimum dependencies. In your example with uri module, it depends on httplib2, so I prefer for using wget which is actually present on almost all systems.