# How to print shell escaped string in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a shell program to output another shell program to be evalled later. Is there some common shell program to print shell escaped for a string?

Comment: `%q` (bash-only) was pointed out below. But mind you, `%q` was broken for more than a decade and only recently fixed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand you question. But the `%q` option of [`printf`](http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html) might be what you are looking for.

> %q Output the corresponding argument in a format that can be reused as shell input

```
printf %q 'C:\ProgramFiles is a Windows path;'
```

outputs `C:\\ProgramFiles\ is\ a\ Windows\ path\;`

(In this example, simple quotes are needed – comment of Gordon Davisson – but this doesn't matter if you print from a variable or the output of a command.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use single quoted string as this is evaluated without any substitution.
For example the following commands are equivalent

```
cat abc\ hi.txt
cat 'abc hi.txt'
```

Comment: This wil fail if the string itself contains a single-quote.