# Why do you have to escape | and + in grep between apostrophes?

Tags: bash, grep, escaping

I was [under the impression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053121/16777) that within single quotes, e.g. `'pattern'`, bash special characters are not interpolated, so one need only escape single quotes themselves.

Why then does `echo "123" | grep '[0-9]+'` output nothing, whereas `echo "123" | grep '[0-9]\+'` (plus sign escaped) output `123`?  (Likewise, `echo "123" | grep '3|4'` outputs nothing unless you escape the `|`.)

This is under bash 4.1.2 and grep 2.6.3 on CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grep` uses *Basic* Regular Expressions, like sed and vi. In that you have to escape metacharacters, and it is tedious.

You probably want *Extended* Regular Expressions, so use `egrep` or `grep -E` (depending on the version in use).  Check your `man grep`.

See also the [GNU documentation](http://gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended) for a full list of the characters involved.

Most languages use Extended Regular Expressions (EREs) these days, and they are much easier to use.  Basic Regular Expressions (BREs) are really a throw-back.

Comment: To clarify: extended regular expressions are not a GNU-ism. They are fully [part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

Comment: @kojiro: yes, both are POSIX.  The GNU documentation has a clear paragraph showing the differences which is why I linked it.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be the regular expression engine that `grep` uses. If you use a different one, it works:

```
$ echo "123" | grep '[0-9]+'
$ echo "123" | grep -P '[0-9]+'
123
$ echo "123" | grep '3|4'
$ echo "123" | grep -P '3|4'
123
```