# Which characters must be masked when using grep and sed?

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I have learned that whene I use the command grep then I must mask those characters `{,},(,)` and `|`
But I have found now an example, where `/` was masked!
Which characters must be masked when using grep and sed command?

Comment: define: "masked". If you mean *escape*, this may be interesting to read [Which characters need to be escaped in Bash? How do we know it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/1983854).

Comment: It depends which mode of `grep`/`sed` you use. `grep 'pattern'`? `grep -P 'perl-pattern'`?

Comment: for example how would you look for /*.....*/

Comment: I'm using grep 'pattern'

Comment: `/` needs to be escaped only inside of sed's `/.../` or `s/.../.../`. It usually cleaner to switch to a different character, though.

Comment: @choroba so in this case can I write :  grep \{/*}[0-9A-Za-z]*\{*/\} ?

Comment: Why `\{`? What about spaces, commas etc. inside of the comments? You also need to backslash asterisks.

Comment: @choroba grep \{/*\}[0-9A-Za-z]*\{*/\}
Could you please tell me the true command for looking for the comment, I think it will helps me better to understand the problem !

Comment: `grep '/\*.*\*/'` might work, but only for single-line comments.

Comment: Thank you! so you did mask or escape the * with \ is that right?

Answer (score 0):

When writing regexes in a shell script, it is normally sensible to enclose the regex in single quotes.  Then you don't have to worry about anything except single quotes that appear in the regex itself.  Occasionally, it may make sense to enclose the regex in double quotes (if it involves matching single quotes and not matching double quotes), but then you have to be careful about `$`, the back-quote  `` ` `` , and backslashes `\`.

So:

```
grep -e '^.*([a-z]*)[[:space:]]*{[^}]*}$'
```

With `sed`, you need to worry about `s///` operations when the search or replacement pattern itself contains slashes `/`.  The simplest technique is to use an alternative character such as `%`:

```
sed -e 's%/where/it/was/%/it/goes/here/now/%'
```

There are three or four dialects of `grep`:

- Plain `grep`
- Extended `grep` (`grep -E`, once upon a time known as `egrep`)
- Fixed `grep` (`grep -F`, once upon a time known as `fgrep`)
- Sometimes you get `grep` with PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expression) support: `grep -P`.

Even within 'plain `grep`', you can find there is some variability between implementations.

Similarly, there are two main dialects of `sed`:

- Plain `sed`
- Extended `sed` (`sed -E` or `sed -r`; `sed -E` is more widely available)

You need to read about POSIX [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (basic regular expressions), supported by plain `grep` and plain `sed`, and POSIX [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (extended regular expressions), supported by `grep -E` and `sed -E` (when EREs are supported by `sed` at all).

See also the POSIX specifications for [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).