# MySQL statement works in mysql but not from command line

Tags: linux, sh

I am trying to execute a particular mysql command from the command line. When I do so, it fails, but if I execute the exact same command from within mysql interactive, it works.

Here is the command line version which fails:

```
$ mysql -uscott -p -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myuser\_%`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';"
```

The error given is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

Copying and pasting just the mysql command into mysql works:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myuser\_%`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

I have taken this command verbatim from phpmyadmin when creating a user for a database. How can I fix it so it works from the command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The * is being expanded by your shell (bash?).

You can fix this by using single quotes around the SQL statement instead of double or escaping the * with a \

Comment: Changing to single quotes worked like a charm. I also tried escaping the *, but mysql didn't like the \\*, so using single quotes for the mysql statement with double quotes inside is the correct and apparently only solution. Thanks!