# cut : use "/" as a delimiter

Tags: bash, cut

I am trying to use the cut command in my bash script. I need to get the name of a rpm package containing 'sys' in its name, without its full path. So I tried this:

```
packageName=$(find temp/noarch/ -name '*sys*noarch.rpm' | cut -d "\/" -f 3)
```

I thought this way could return the package's name without the temp/noarch/, but it only tells me.

I know i could just remove the substring `"temp\/noarch\/"`, but i'd like to make it with cut.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`"\/"` doesn't expand to `/`, so `cut` complains:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Use plain `/` instead:

```
packageName=$(find temp/noarch/ -name '*sys*noarch.rpm' | cut -d/ -f3)
```

Comment: Strange thing that linux does not need here to receive a `\/`. Anyway, worked fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Eos: Strange? Where **does** it need a backslash before slash?

Comment: I am working with files with paths inside. So, when searching for those paths, i was searching `"path\/of\/a\/file\/"`, for the character escaping. I got used to it. My bad.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-bash-how-do-we-know-it

Comment: How about for ! ... ?