# eval expression with environment variables

Tags: bash, shell, julia

Version 0.6

I want to use julias -e(val) option with environment variables. How can I do that?

Example:

```
y=10
echo $y
julia -e 'println($y)'
```

the echo works, as expected. But the julia line does not work. `ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression $`. Now how do I make this work?

I tried it with ENV["y"] but it does not find the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not really Julia related, but more shell related. The shell does not replace environment variables in strings surrounded by `'` (single quote), but does replace them in double quoted strings (surrounded by `"`). So the solution would be to do:

```
julia -e "println($y)"
```

The issues become more complicated if you want to use the `$` sign in the Julia expression or `"` itself - for these there are documented escaping rules. See, for example:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting
- [Which characters need to be escaped in Bash? How do we know it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-bash-how-do-we-know-it)
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Answer (score 3):

You can alternatively indeed use the `ENV` variable. Environment variables are [not available to subprocesses unless they are `export`ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export). So a revision of your code,

```
export y=10
echo $y
julia -e 'println(ENV["y"])'
```

would work fine.