# How can I enter text into Launchy and append it to the end of a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, echo

I'm a Debian Stretch user coming from Windows. In Windows with the `launchy` app (also available for Linux), I had a method of entering text into `launchy` that was then appended to the end of a `.txt` or `.md` file.

To do this in Windows, I created a file called `note.bat` that contained the following:
`echo %*>>"C:\collectednotes.md"`

I'd make `launchy` aware of `note.bat` by adding its containing folder to “Launchy” → “Settings” → “Catalog” and adding filetype `*.bat`.

From there, I'd launch `launchy`, type `note`, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, enter some text, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then the text would be added to the end of `collectednotes.md`.

A mostly working process is detailed in my answer below. **I'll give the green checkmark answer to anyone that can adjust this process (via `note.sh` and/or launchy plugin setup detailed below) to appropriately handle all special characters.**

This may contain the solution to this question:
[Which characters need to be escaped in Bash? How do we know it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-bash-how-do-we-know-it)

Comment: I can sort-of see what you're doing here; but is your text file so huge and unwieldy that you can't just make a desktop shortcut that opens it in a text editor? FWIW I guess the Linux equivalent of of your batch script would be something like `echo "$@" >> /path/to/text/file`

Comment: @KevinBoone The idea is to remove as much friction/distraction as possible in taking notes. The idea is popular in the "GTD" community. This is the earliest I recall seeing it: http://www.43folders.com/2004/09/04/quicksilver-append-to-a-text-file-from-anywhere

Comment: Hello @KevinBoone - please see the partial solution below. Thanks for the early input - your comment is part of the solution. An additional issue with creating shortcuts and just opening text file: 1) always have to `ctrl`+`end` if you want top to bottom to log oldest to newest 2) have to close the file after each note or keep it open and tolerate the clutter and 3) possible to get distracted by having to confront previously saved text. You'll have to try it to become a believer!

Answer (score 0):

Solved (almost). I'm keeping this question unanswered and will give to whoever completes the remaining ~5%. Steps to get the 95% solution with `xfce4-terminal` version `0.8.3-1`:

Install `launchy` and `launchy-plugins` (both are version 2.5-4 for me):
`apt-get install launchy`
`apt-get install launchy-plugins`

Open terminal to default location of `~/` and create `collectednotes.md`:
`echo "# Launchy Notes Collected Here" > collectednotes.md`

Create `note.sh` shell script:
`echo '#!/bin/sh' > note.sh`

Create shell script line 2:
`echo ALL_ARGUMENTS='"$@"' >> note.sh`

Create shell script line 3:
`echo 'echo "$ALL_ARGUMENTS" >> ~/collectednotes.md' >> note.sh`

If you open `note.sh`, it will look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
ALL_ARGUMENTS="$@"
echo "$ALL_ARGUMENTS" >> ~/collectednotes.md
```

Make `note.sh` executable:
`chmod +x note.sh`

Launch `launchy` and click the gear icon in upper right for settings. If consistency with `launchy` for Windows is desired, set `launchy` Hotkey to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. If you receive a keyboard shortcut conflict message as I do on Debian with Xfce, first go to Settings, Window Manager, Keyboard tab, and clear <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as the shortcut for Window operations menu.

Next in `launchy` settings, go to Plugins tab and enable the plugin `Runner`. Click the `+` button and create a new `Runner` custom command as follows:
- Name: `note`
- Program: `/home/YOURUSERNAMEHERE/note.sh`  (`launchy` does not like Program path of `~/note.sh`, so a specific path with username is required)
- Arguments: `'$$'`

Click the Catalog tab and hit `Rescan Catalog` just in case. Hit `OK` to close `launchy` settings.

Now let's test it.
- launch `launchy` with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or your hotkey
- type `note` (You may have to wait 10 second or so on first run. You'll know things are as expected when you see the text "note" with a orange/yellow icon containing silhouette of a person.)
- hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- enter some text (no need for single or double quotes or escapes), e.g.: `Remember to donate at least $3 to Josh at Launchy https://www.launchy.net/donate.php`
- hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now open `collectednotes.md` to confirm the text was captured.

The remaining issues seem to be dealing with single quotes and double quotes. For example, consider the following note:
`I don't know what I'd do without Launchy.`

Which results in the following in `collectednotes.md`:
`I dont know what Id do without Launchy.`

Or:
`Would David Allen like universal text capture from anywhere in Linux? My bet is "yes!"`

Results in the following in `collectednotes.md`:
`Would David Allen like universal text capture from anywhere in Linux? My bet is \yes!\`

Single quoting and/or double quoting the input to `launchy` doesn't solve it. Note the `launchy` `Runner` custom plugin construction component of `'$$'` is a piece of this puzzle.

**I'll give the answer to anyone that can adjust this process (via `note.sh` and/or `launchy` plugin setup) to appropriately handle all special characters.** Maybe this would add proper escapes to user input with something like `gsub`.

The rationale for being exacting regarding proper character handling is that this process is useful for copying and logging random chunks of text from web pages, but if common characters like single quotes are not handled as expected, confidence in the system is much reduced.