# Remove two files ending by ~ and # in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Why is not working? 
I'm trying to remove files ending by ~ and #

```
find . (-name "*~" -o -name "*#") -delete
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the paranthesis so they get interpreted by `find`, not by the shell.

```
mkdir testme
cd testme
touch "foo~"
touch "bar#"
ls

# With parenthesis escaped
find . \( -name "*~" -o -name "*#" \) -delete

ls
cd ..
rmdir testme
```

Answer (score 3):

In POSIX shells (incl. bash) you need to escape the parentheses.

```
find .  \( -name "*~" -o -name "*#"  \) -delete
```

Here's a working example (run in an empty directory)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -eu
mkdir -p a/b/c d/e f
touch a/a~ a/b/b~ 'd/e/e#' 'f/f#' 'root#' 'root~'
find .  \( -name "*~" -o -name "*#"  \) -delete
find .
```