# Bash To Convert PDF Files In Multiple Subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, type-conversion

I am attempting to convert PDF files in 2,432 subdirectories (one PDF file per folder) to HTML files.

For example, I have tried a few variations of

```
find . -type d | while read d; for file in *.pdf; do pdftohtml -c -i -s "$file"; done
```

and

```
for f in ./*/*.pdf; do pdftohtml -c -i -s "$file"; done
```

without any success. I have also tried some others, however, I just can't get anything to work this time.

I know that part of the code works because I can put multiple PDF files in one folder and use

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftohtml -c -i -s "$file"; done
```

to recursively convert all of the files in that folder to HTML.

Is there a way that I can search through each folder and convert each file with a bash script? Or is this something I will have to do one folder at a time?

Comment: Do you want to have the html files generated in the same directory as the source pdf file?

Comment: Certainly! Having the converted files in the same folder as the PDF is what I was hoping to do. Sorry, I forgot to include that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` command with the option `-exec` to trigger the conversion:

```
find /path/to/your/root/pdf/folder -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec bash -c 'pdftohtml -c -i -s "$1"' _ {} \;
```

The `pdftohtml` is executed for every pdf file found. Note that `{}` represents the pdf file.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `-exec bash ...` over `-exec pdftohtml ... {}` ?

Comment: @Socowi In this case maybe not, but in the general case where you need execute bash builtin command, the `bash -c` is required.

Comment: Well, this worked like a champ! I want to play with some of the other solutions for learning purposes, but this just flew right through and converted everything in each folder. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Your second command seemed about right. There was just one little error

> `for f in ./*/*.pdf; do pdftohtml -c -i -s "$file"; done`

You wrote `for f` but used `$file`. Try

```
for f in ./*/*.pdf; do pdftohtml -c -i -s "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
find . -name \*.pdf -exec pdftohtml -c -i -s {} \;
```

Comment: I want to try this, as well. What is the purpose of escaping the *.pdf? I'm still learning bash, regex, etc., and don't think I've come across anything that has used an escape yet. That makes it really short and clean!

Comment: well, I had some troubles in the past with some files, so I escape. We can use "*.pdf" with no escape.

Comment: see more about escaping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash

Comment: Got it. Many years ago a PHP mentor taught me the habit of prevention (a few keystrokes now can save you from a million later on.) Seems to apply here, as well. Thank you for the info and the link!