# remove shell escape characters from a string

Tags: python, shell, terminal, scripting, escaping

I am creating a terminal based python application whereby the user drags and drops a csv file into the terminal to get the file path. The file path is therefore escaped.

How do I remove all instances of this?

For example, I have a file

```
thisisatestfile/\(2).csv
```

but when I drag it into terminal it appears as:

```
thisisatestfile\:\\\(2\).csv
```

I have a list of all the shell escape characters that I need to remove:
[link to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash)

I am not very good at regex so any help much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should use the [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module to parse the input.

Comment: forgot to say, must work on 2.7.10

Comment: Create a dictionary that maps each of the escape sequences to the corresponding replacement. Then use `re.sub()` to replace them all.

Comment: @Barmar you can use the shlex library in python 2.7.10 therefore am using this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this with [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)

```
>>> shlex.split('thisisatestfile/\(2).csv')
['thisisatestfile/(2).csv']
```

Since this method is intended for taking a raw shell invocation and returning a list of args to be passed to, e.g., [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), it returns a list. If you know you only have a single string to process, just grab the first element of the returned list.

```
>>> shlex.split('thisisatestfile/\(2).csv')[0]
'thisisatestfile/(2).csv'
```