# How to use sed to replace "word{word" or "word}word"

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I tried to write a bash-script to replace things like:

```
{"Ausstattung":"

"},{"Ausstattung":"

"}
```

in all `CSV` files of a subfolder.

This is what I am using so far:

```
function suche_und_ersetze() { // search and replace
   LC_ALL=C find ./subfolder -type f ! -name ".DS_Store" -exec sed -i "" "s/${OLD}/${NEW}/g" {} \; 
}

OLD='{\"Ausstattung\":\"' 
NEW="#" 
suche_und_ersetze

OLD='\"},{\"Ausstattung\":\"'
NEW=" #" 
suche_und_ersetze

OLD='\"}' 
NEW="" 
suche_und_ersetze
```

Somehow I can't make it work. The script is replacing text without `"` or `}` or `,`,  but not the upper listed words.

Comment: You'll want to pass your OLD and NEW variables as parameters to your function.
They can then be called with `$1` and `$2`.
Bash goes from top to bottom, your `suche_und_ersetze` function doesn't know what `${OLD}` and `${NEW}` are

Comment: Thank you @SimonC-ReinstateMonica. It is working with other Texts, f.ex. only Ausstattung. But not with the Brackets...

Comment: I did some language polishing and a bit of translation to English to improve readability.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,
i should have looked into the csv with an editor:

It is
""},{""Ausstattung"":""
and not
"},{"Ausstattung":"

In sed you even don't need to escape " if you use '

Comment: Please try rewording your answer, https://www.deepl.com/ might help you. In the current form it is hard to guess what you suggest.