# Complex string with special characters substitutions

Tags: shell, sed, terminal, string-substitution

I've to substitute the string `blacklist:[/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/]` with
`blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/, /\/first|\/second|\/third/]` in a file.
I would like to use `sed`command to do it in shell.
I opted to use ~ as separator and I tried with variables but nothing happened.

Example:

`VarA="blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/]"`

`VarB="blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/, /\/first|\/second|\/third/]"`

`sed "s~$VarA~$VarB~" service-worker.js`

Could you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed helps. If that looks complicated, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some meta-characters like `\` `[` `$` must be quoted in single quotes (which is not possible in your case) or escaped (with backslash, which must escaped with itself too)

you can use string manipulation for replacing

run this function over your strings

```
escape() {
  local var="$1"

  var="${var//\\/\\\\}" # \
  var="${var//\[/\\\[}" # [
  var="${var//\$/\\\$}" # $
  printf "%s" "$var"

  return 0
}

VarA=$(escape "$VarA")
VarB=$(escape "$VarB")
```

Comment: there is maybe easier way just `printf -v VarA '%q' "$VarA"` but my version of printf does error *"bad format"* https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701

Comment: `. ^ *` should be escaped too. also please choose other name for function (may exist) https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't understand literal strings, just use a tool that does like awk:

```
$ cat file
foo
blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/]
bar

$ VarA='blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/]'

$ VarB='blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/, /\/first|\/second|\/third/]'

$ VarA="$VarA" VarB="$VarB" awk '
    BEGIN { old=ENVIRON["VarA"]; lgth=length(old); new=ENVIRON["VarB"] }
    s = index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+lgth) }
    { print }
' file 
foo
blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^\/?]+\.[^\/]+$/, /\/first|\/second|\/third/]
bar
```