# How to echo variable input into a file

Tags: shell, asterisk, quotes, single-quotes

I need to invoke a shell call from Asterisk dialplan in order to log some data to a text file, so I tried this:

```
Set(log=[${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}] [${UNIQUEID}] ${ARG1})
SYSTEM(echo "${log}" >> /var/log/asterisk/log.txt)
```

(No assumptions can be made about the contents of `ARG1`. It may contain single quotes, double quotes, ampersands, or any other characters.)

This seemed to work, but I recently found calls that had `&` in their caller ID were being dropped as soon as they entered the switch because the function crashed and the call dropped.

I tried replacing double quotes in the `echo` statement with single quotes, but if the caller ID name contains a single quote, the function will not crash but it does not echo anything at all.

Here is my dilemma:

- I cannot escape anything (at least manually). `ARG1` is variable per call, and could be literally anything. As such, this isn't a static string where I can simply escape quotes.
- I cannot use a HEREDOC, which is what seems to be the recommended approach. I am invoking a shell call using SYSTEM() which gives me one shot to execute shell code. I can't have a bunch of separate lines for all that EOF stuff.
- I don't see how I can pass this into a bash script to do that, either. I would need to get the entire $log variable into a script in order to do the HEREDOC stuff there, and I'll have the same problem as I'm having now - how to get the whole thing there intact, without causing an error.
- Since this is a single shell call, whatever command or commands I run needs to be a bash one-liner.

The variable log itself does not contain any variables when expanded. Is there any way here to make the echoing work as desired?

Comment: did you try to escape special char or use printf instead of echo? This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash

Comment: @Lety I did look into the printf %q thing, which seemed promising, but can't get that to work, either. Same problem as just doing echo '${log}'. I think the issue is it's not a bash variable, it's a variable in the program I'm using, and when it gets to the SYSTEM/shell call it's already been substituted so that all bash sees is a string literal that isn't quoted right.

Comment: @oguzismail I could, but I want to log the original Caller ID number and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you "cannot escape anything?" Put the string in single quotes, and all you need to escape is [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings). This could be done with [the `REPLACE` function](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Function_REPLACE).

```
Set(log=[${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}] [${UNIQUEID}] ${REPLACE(${ARG1},','"'"')})
SYSTEM(echo '${log}' >> /var/log/asterisk/log.txt)
```

But I think the cleaner solution is to use [the `FILE` function](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Function_FILE) instead.

```
FILE(/var/log/asterisk/log.txt,,,a)=${log}
```

Comment: The FILE function is just what's needed here - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Common, people. Why you are trying re-invite wheel?

Just use CEL in csv file or QueueLog function, think twice before using System call. It has a HUGE security risk.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+CEL+Specification

(see "User Defined" section)

Sure you can use Verbose and Log apps and setup log files to do your level in different file.
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Logging