# JMeterLibException: 'Value returned by JMeter: 1'

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

when i try to pass current testcase (-Jtestname=${TEST_NAME}
) name along with run jmeter robot keyword getting below error,

JMeterLibException: 'Value returned by JMeter: 1'

```
Run Jmeter    ${jmeter}    ${jmxPath}  ${logPath}   -Jpath=${mdmpath} -Jtestname=${TEST_NAME}
```

My test case name is "AREA MDM"

As per below log info testcase name is getting assigned against -Jtestname but still getting this exception error,

```
19:27:46.574    INFO    Starting JMeter with following parameters:
 - JMeter path: /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh
 - Test plan path: /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BizomWebMDM.jmx
 - Log file path: /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/Output/log.jtl
 - Other parameters: -Jpath=../BizomWeb/venv/resources/Excel/MDM/areas.xls -Jtestname=AREA MDM .
subprocess.call input list: ['/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh', '-n', '-t', '/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BizomWebMDM.jmx', '-l', '/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/Output/log.jtl', '-Jpath=../BizomWeb/venv/resources/Excel/MDM/areas.xls', '-Jtestname=AREA', 'MDM']   
19:27:46.575    FAIL    JMeterLibException: 'Value returned by JMeter: 1'   
19:27:46.575    DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sadha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 41, in runJmeter
    JMeterRunner(jmeterPath, testPlanPath, logFilePath, otherParams)
  File "/home/sadha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 200, in __init__
    jmeterOutput = self.runAndPrintResult()
  File "/home/sadha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 234, in runAndPrintResult
    raise JMeterLibException("%s %s" % (msg, retValue))
```

If i pass any dummy string it will work but facing issue ony when i pass current testcase name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your `AREA MDM` stanza with quotation marks like:

```
-Jtestname="${TEST_NAME}"
```

or escape each character which needs to be escaped using backslash like change `AREA MDM` to `AREA\ MDM`

More information:

- [Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)