# Jmeter error integer expression expected while trying to run jmx file from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jmeter, dockerfile, performance-testing

I have written the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
#s3 bucket name
export AWS_PROFILE=tahashin
S3_BUCKET="oa-eui-dev-plt-env-kpidev-oa"
export jmsxfilename=$1
testconfigfolder="$S3_BUCKET/loadtest/TestConfiguration"
propertiesfile=testconfig.properties
jmetertestfolder="$S3_BUCKET/loadtest/testscripts"
#download test configuration file
echo "Downloading configuration and jmx file"
aws s3 cp s3://$testconfigfolder/$propertiesfile Test_configuration/
aws s3 cp s3://$jmetertestfolder/$jmsxfilename Tests_folder/
#set filename
varsFilename="Test_configuration/$propertiesfile"
scriptname="Tests_folder/$jmsxfilename"
#set env variable using csv file
#declare host,schema,Bearer,Customer_Universe,Consent
#count=0
#while IFS=, read -r name value; 
#do
# echo "Name and value of the variable  is : $name $value"
#((++count))
#done < <(tail -n +2 $varsFilename)

#set Jmeter configuration
resultfile=$(echo $scriptname | sed -e s~\.jmx )

#run jmeter script
echo "Jmeter test starting"
D:/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh -q $varsFilename -n -t $scriptname -l results/results.csv
echo "Jmeter test finished"
sudo rm -rf Test_configuration/$varsFilename
read -p "Press any key to resume ..."
```

The purpose of writing this shell script is: jmx and properties file will be s3. Jmx file will be executed in a docker container using aws fargate. Fargate will be created by aws batch job. But after a while trying to execute this script in my local windows machine, I am getting following error
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo` is available on your system, then probably it's not located in your `PATH`. Run this:

```sh
export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin"
```

You can verify which path to add by running one of the commands below.

```sh
$ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
$ whereis sudo
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/sudo /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think [`sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/) command exists in Git Bash, if you really need it for anything - consider installing [win-sudo](https://github.com/imachug/win-sudo) however I don't see any sense in it, you can just remove it.
2. You need to have `java.exe` in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) so add something like:

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Common\ Files/Oracle/Java/bin
   ```

   to the script you "have written"

   The same applies to all the variables, either surround them with quotation marks or make sure that all [characters which need escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053121/2897748) are escaped with the back slash like in the above example

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)