# python bash how to escape character '!'?

Tags: python, bash, escaping

python/bash how to escape character '!'

I am try to run in Python this

`c.run('sqlcmd -U nrv -P PP!asword -Q "select top 3 * from sys.databases"', pty = True)`

code in brackets - bash code

it works in terminal in that manner:

`sqlcmd -U nrv -P PP\!asword -Q "select top 3 * from sys.databases"`

in genereal i try nothing meaningful

Comment: What is `c`? A command in a module?

Comment: If it's an option, I would recommend not involving the shell at all, e.g. `subprocess.run(["sqlcmd", "-U", "nrv", "-P", "PP!asword", ...])`. Then you don't have to worry about escaping anything.

Comment: 'c' is Connection from Fabric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has answer!
`c.sudo(r'''sqlcmd -U nrv -P PP!asword -Q "select top 3 * from sys.databases"''')`
(in that case I've changed run to sudo because sufficient privileges)

so, I newbie in Python, and heared about "sсreened" strings  - and it simply works.it's even strange that a backslash was not required, because command in brackets - it is a bash, and it requires.

Comment: There is a well regarded answer  already provided at Stack regarding escape characters, including!.  
The exhausting  list of answers to bash escape characters are found at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply prefixing the "**!**" with "**\**" inside your single-quotes in the first form of the equation ?  Single-quotes are meant to be taken as literals, so the backslash will be passed thru, exactly as your command-line attempt.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. In error message i see, that resulted password was PP\!asword
PP\\!asword