# Escape double and single quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, cron

I have a Cron Job running quarterly on every first Sunday of the Month:

```
0 0 1-7 3,6,9,12 * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Sun" ] && /script.sh
```

Now I want to install it automatically using echo like:

```
(crontab -l ; echo "0 0 1-7 3,6,9,12 * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Sun" ] && /script.sh") | crontab -
```

while escaping `\"Sun"\` works fine I can't escape `"$(date '+\%a')"` as this is a mix of single and double quotes with `\` within double quoted echo command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use crazy escaping. Use `[[ ... ]]` provided by `bash` instead of old (and error prone) `[ ... ]`:

So use:

```
0 0 1-7 3,6,9,12 * [[ $(date +\%a) == Sun ]] && /script.sh
```

And to install it automatically use:

```
(crontab -l ; echo '0 0 1-7 3,6,9,12 * [[ $(date +\%a) == Sun ]] && /script.sh') | crontab -
```

PS: Make sure to set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the crontab file before this line.

Comment: Since `[[ ]]` isn't available in all shells, if you're going to use this solution you should set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the crontab file *before* this line. Also, you still need to escape the `%`, so cron doesn't treat it as a line break.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson, very good points. I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) to avoid having to quote the crontab entry:

```
read -r crontab_entry <<'END_CRONTAB_ENTRY'
0 0 1-7 3,6,9,12 * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Sun" ] && /script.sh
END_CRONTAB_ENTRY

(crontab -l; printf '%s\n' "$crontab_entry") | crontab -
```

- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of  `echo` to output the crontab entry.
- Note that `date '+\%a'` produces output like `\Sun` (for some versions of the `date` program).  You probably want `date '+%a'`.
  (**Update:** the [comment by Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855144/escape-double-and-single-quotes-in-bash/71856676?noredirect=1#comment126986993_71856676) explains that the backslash in `date '+\%a'` is necessary because the command is in a `crontab`.)
- Note also that the string produced by the `%a` date format depends on the locale.  It could be something other than `Sun` for Sunday.  It's safer to use a numeric day (e.g. `[ "$(date '+%w')" -eq 0 ]`).
- Finally, note that using `==` with `[...]` is not portable between shells.  Use `=` unless you are *sure* that the crontab entries will only be run with Bash.

Comment: Both `date '+%a'` and `date '+\%a'`  produce `Wed` for me in Debian (5.0.3(1)) and Ubuntu (5.0.17(1))

Comment: @SynRomana, `date '+\%a'` currently outputs `\Wed` for me.  I guess it's due to having a different version of the `date` program.

Comment: The escape before `%` is crontab syntax, and will not be executed as part of the actual `date` command. See ["How is `%` special in crontab?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277508/how-is-special-in-crontab)