# Why does my monthly command in my cron file does not work while daily commands do work?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I am managing a system built by third parts on a Ubuntu OS.

There is a line in a cron file which - every first day of the month at hour 07:00 - should trigger a bash script which calls an ansible playbook, and produce a log with the information about the execution.

chain of calls:

cron file -> bash script -> ansible playbook

However this does not work: the script does not run, the log does not get generated.

What is the problem ?

### Context

The cron file is `/etc/cron.d/ansible-cron`, and the line of the case is

```
00 07 1 * * myuser /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/collect_sale_statistics.sh >/home/myuser/var/log/collect_sale_statistics-$(date +\%Y-%m).log 2>&1
```

the bash script permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser 493 Mar 23 17:42 collect_sale_statistics.sh*
```

and its content is

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am
/home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-venv/bin/ansible-playbook playbooks/collect_sale_statistics/main.yml
```

In my machine, the same routine is implemented for some daily and weekly playbooks which successfully work.

e.g.

The cron `/etc/cron.d/ansible-cron` also contains:

```
# collect number of reboot in the last week every monday
00 07 * * 1 myuser /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/count_reboots.sh >/home/myuser/var/log/count_reboots-$(date +\%w).log 2>&1
```

the bash script permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser 771 Feb  8  2023 /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/count_reboots.sh*
```

and its content is

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am
/home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-venv/bin/ansible-playbook playbooks/count_reboots.yml
```

The script `count_reboots.sh` runs fine, the log is generated, etc.

### error analysis

**1. About the error location**

What I see is that the log was not generated, so I guess that the process breaks before when or before the command in the cron is executed. 
So the problem must be in the cron. 
For sure it is not in the ansible playbook.

If I manually run in the terminal

```
bash /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/collect_sale_statistics.sh
```

the script runs fine, just the automatic execution which should be triggered by the cron does not start.

So I guess the problem lies somewhere between the cron file and the accessibility to the bash script.

**2. About the cron syntax**

I have verified on crontab.guru that [`00 07 1 * *`](https://crontab.guru/#00_07_1_*_*) ( the cron time set for `collect_sale_statistics.sh` ) correctly means "At 07:00 on day-of-month 1."
This message is slightly unclear, as "day-of-month 1" could be interpreted as "day-of month1", which is January, so "every day in January".
However, this is not the case, as I have also verified on crontab.guru that "every day in January" is cron-transcoded as [`00 07 * 1 *`](https://crontab.guru/#00_07_*_1_*) , for which crontab.guru indicates "At 07:00 in January.".

**3. About the cron folder**

I suspect the problem might be in the fact that I am placing a command which is supposed to run monthly in a folder `/etc/cron.d/` which should be dedicated to cron files which should contain comands to be run daily.

However, the same cron file contains a command which is run weekly, and it runs fine.

Comment: @pmf No. By using crontab.guru I have verified that `00 07 * 1 *` means "At 07:00 in January." While `00 07 1 * *` means "At 07:00 on day-of-month 1.".  I have updated the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the cron tag states: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Comment: I would trust _man 5 crontab_ more than crontab.guru. The man-page says that the 3rd parameter is the day of the month, and the forth is the month.  Hence `00 07 * 1 *` would be every day in January.

Comment: You've only escaped one of the percent signs in the command (in the date format); you need to escape both of them.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that is not the problem. If I copy that line of code form the cron and manually launch it in the terminal, the script gets executed fine.

Comment: @Tms91 Percent signs have a special meaning in crontab entries, and must be escaped to avoid this special meaning; this does not apply on a normal command line. See ["How is % (percent sign) special in crontab?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277508/how-is-percent-sign-special-in-crontab) and the troubleshooting section of the [cron tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks! I bet this is the reason why it did not work. if you want to post an answer, I will flag it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As quoted by @GordonDavisson and by [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277891/7658051), the manpage documentation for cron says:

```
...
Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), 
will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the 
first % will be sent to the command  as standard input.
...
```

so my line

```
00 07 1 * * myuser /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/collect_sale_statistics.sh >/home/myuser/var/log/collect_sale_statistics-$(date +\%Y-%m).log 2>&1
```

would result in

```
00 07 1 * * myuser /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/collect_sale_statistics.sh >/home/myuser/var/log/collect_sale_statistics-$(date +\%Y-
# new line
m).log 2>&1
```

and break the cron file.

In the first line above, I have added an escape (`\`) character before the percent sign of the month variable (`%m`), so now it is

```
00 07 1 * * myuser /home/myuser/var/myfolder/ansible-am/collect_sale_statistics.sh >/home/myuser/var/log/collect_sale_statistics-$(date +\%Y-\%m).log 2>&1
```